# Making exe file with Python including database

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qt-designer

I am developing a desktop application with pyqt5 (Python). The application contains back end database.

Let us say for example I created a table for employee in company (database name) database in MYSQL. My application has an interface to store employee details. Now I want to create single executable file with my database and application. I want to install that application in client's mechine, which have no internet. Now i want to know how to do that and what software is needed at client's system.

My sources for the task is below:

- Window 10 (clients system)
- My executable file (.exe file) ---> I am using MYSQL and pyqt5 (Python)

1. How to create this exe file which includes company database?
2. What software is needed at client`s system in order to run this application successfully?

If possible, give me step by step guidelines.

Comment: This question is not duplicate of the question mentioned. That questions doesn't  ask for `mysql` dependency, whereas this one does.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need to perform.

1. First you need to install `pyinstaller` and create a onedir executable folder
2. Download [Inno Setup Installer](https://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php).
3. Create a installer and add all your project files while creating the installer.
4. Copy this single installer file(*.exe) in your client's machine.
5. Install the exe. It will automatically add your files to the desired location.

*Note: Creating Inno Setup executable is not that easy task it is better if you watch any tutorial of creating a installer on youtube first.